# Three photon amplitude in QED

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, correlation-functions

When we evaluate the amplitude of the three-photon interaction in QED, we find out that the amplitude of the following diagrams cancel out.[image]

In the limit of $m_e \rightarrow0$ it boils down into trace identities to show that the amplitude is indeed zero. I can do that, but my question is why is this a significant result for us to assume that QED is renormalizable. I have read that it is esential for this interaction to vanish. Why ?

Comment: Ma&ybe because the divergence of each diagram is too "severe" for getting removed with renormalization of "something".

Comment: By the way, this amplitude vanishes trivially by Furry's Theorem

Comment: Do you have any further reading material(or explanation) on the subject??

Comment: Mostly I'd like to know why this process is important for the renormalizability of QED

Answer (score 4):

I'm extremely late. The reason is that otherwise one would have to insert a counterterm in the Lagrangian that is cubic in the electromagnetic field. This term would break gauge invariance.

Comment: All of the amplitudes with an odd power of the EM field are in fact zero by Furry's theorem, so that a need to renormalize them is never necessary

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425287)